# Calculate Similarity multi dimensions array Using fastdtw

Tags: python, python-3.x, similarity

I have trying to use **fastdtw** to calculate similarity

Here is the working example: The similarity is 0.916%.

```
dataSetI = [1, 0.5, 2, 2]
dataSetII = [1, 1, 1, 0.51, 2, 1]

x = np.array(dataSetI)
y = np.array(dataSetII)

distance, path = fastdtw(x, y, dist=euclidean)
print("{:.3f}%".format(similarity))#0.916%
```

But the dataset I am going to compare is a multidimensional array, random index length
Example:

```
dataSetI = [[1, 0.5], [2, 2],[]]]
dataSetII = [[1, 1,3,5], [1, 0.51], [2, 1,5,6,7]]

x = np.array(dataSetI)
y = np.array(dataSetII)

distance, path = fastdtw(x, y, dist=euclidean)
#error here
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So my question is: Am I able to do this using **fastdtw**? Or is there any library able to do this? Please let me know. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Nooo! Dont use FastDTW

FastDTW is approximate and Generally Slower than the Algorithm it Approximates
Renjie Wu, Eamonn J. Keogh: ICDE 2021: 2327-2328